# Node - logging versions of TLS for outbound connections?

Tags: node.js, tls1.2

I'd like to log which versions of TLS my Node app is using, if possible without changing any code.

I've tried both `NODE_DEBUG=tls,http`, and `DEBUG=*` which of course added lots of info to the logs, but nothing about the TLS versions in use.

Is this possible ?

Comment: How about using tcpdump or wireshark?

Comment: You want to do this for what? Requests that your code makes? Can you give some more context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about not changing code, but you can log like this:

```
const tls = require('tls');

const url = 'someurl';
console.log('Connecting..');

const socket = tls.connect(443, url, () => {
  console.log('Tls.connect', socket.authorized ? 'authorized' : 'unauthorized');  
  console.log('Cipher: ' + JSON.stringify(socket.getCipher()));
  console.log('Protocol: ' + JSON.stringify(socket.getProtocol()));
});
```

This will give an output like this:

```
Listening...
Connecting..
Tls.connect authorized
Cipher: {"name":"ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256","version":"TLSv1/SSLv3"}
Protocol: "TLSv1.2"
```

Comment: hey... thanks for the response... though this doesnt 100% do what I want, I appreciate the effort!

Comment: Great! I played about with NODE_DEBUG settings (and other ones) but I couldn't get exactly where you wanted to be.