# Axios/HTTPS certificate expired error only on Windows

Tags: node.js, typescript, https, axios, tls1.2

I am currently working on a VSCode extension that internally makes some API calls to a HTTPS protected endpoint. On Linux and Mac OS the extension works as expected but on Windows machines `axios`, the internal HTTP client used to make the API calls, is rejecting those requests due to the certificates being expired. When I access the API endpoint though via Firefox, Chrome and even Edge the certificates seems find.

I have upgraded Node to 16.14.0 and also to 17.6.0 but the problem still remains. As the API is only accessible through our VPN, with my VPN activated of course, I used [testssl.sh](https://testssl.sh/) to verify that the whole trust-chain is still valid:

```
 Testing protocols via sockets except NPN+ALPN                                                                                                                                
                                                                                                                                                                              
 SSLv2      not offered (OK)                                                                                                                                                  
 SSLv3      not offered (OK)                                                                                                                                                  
 TLS 1      not offered                                                                                                                                                       
 TLS 1.1    not offered                                                                                                                                                       
 TLS 1.2    offered (OK)                                                                                                                                                      
 TLS 1.3    offered (OK): final                                                                                                                                               
 NPN/SPDY   not offered                                                                                                                                                       
 ALPN/HTTP2 h2, http/1.1 (offered)                                                                                                                                            
                                                                                                                                                                              
 Testing cipher categories                                                                                                                                                    
                                                                                                                                                                              
 NULL ciphers (no encryption)                  not offered (OK)                                                                                                               
 Anonymous NULL Ciphers (no authentication)    not offered (OK)                                                                                                               
 Export ciphers (w/o ADH+NULL)                 not offered (OK)                                                                                                               
 LOW: 64 Bit + DES, RC[2,4] (w/o export)       not offered (OK)                                                                                                               
 Triple DES Ciphers / IDEA                     not offered                                                                                                                    
 Obsolete CBC ciphers (AES, ARIA etc.)         offered                                                                                                                        
 Strong encryption (AEAD ciphers)              offered (OK)                                                                                                                   


 Testing robust (perfect) forward secrecy, (P)FS -- omitting Null Authentication/Encryption, 3DES, RC4 

 PFS is offered (OK)          TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256 ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384 ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA
                              DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256 DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256
                              ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256 DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA 
 Elliptic curves offered:     prime256v1 secp384r1 secp521r1 X25519 X448 
 DH group offered:            HAProxy (2048 bits)

 Testing server preferences 

 Has server cipher order?     yes (OK) -- TLS 1.3 and below
 Negotiated protocol          TLSv1.3
 Negotiated cipher            TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, 253 bit ECDH (X25519)
 Cipher order
    TLSv1.2:   ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256 ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA
               ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384 ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256 DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256 DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA 
    TLSv1.3:   TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256 TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 
...
 Certificate Validity (UTC)   65 >= 30 days (2022-02-01 08:18 --> 2022-05-02 08:18)
...
```

The other certificates in the trustchain are also valid and not expired at all.

Axios is used within an own `HttpClient` class that looks like this:

```js
export class HttpClient {

    private readonly instance: AxiosInstance;

    constructor() {
        this.instance = axios.create();
    }

    async asyncGet<T>(url: string): Promise<Response<T>> {
        return this.instance.get<T>(url)
            .then(axiosResponse => {
                ...
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error(error);
                throw error;
            });
    }
}
```

I also tried the `https`

```js
const options: https:RequestOptions = {
    hostname: '...',
    port: 443,
    path: '/...',
    method: 'GET'
};
const request = https.request(url, options, (res: IncomingMessage) => {
    console.log(`statusCode: ${res.statusCode ? res.statusCode : 'undefined'}`);
    res.on('data', d => {
        process.stdout.write(d as string);
    }
});
request.on('error', error => {
    console.error(error);
};
request.end();
```

analog to the samples given in the [NodeJS documentation](https://nodejs.dev/learn/making-http-requests-with-nodejs) and `tls`

```js
const socket = tls.connect(443, hostname, undefined, () => {
    console.log('Connected to ' + hostname);
    console.log('TLS.connect', socket.authorized ? 'authorized' : 'unauthorized');
    console.log('Cipher: ' + JSON.stringify(socket.getCipher()));
    console.log('Protocol: ' + JSON.stringify(socket.getProtocol()));
    const peerCert: tls.DetailedPeerCertificate = socket.getPeerCertificate(true);
    console.log(`Peer-Cert ${JSON.stringify(peerCert.subject)} - valid from: ${peerCert ? peerCert.valid_from : 'invalid'} valid till: ${peerCert ? peerCert.valid_to : 'invalid'}`);
    const issuerCert = peerCert.issuerCertificate;
    console.log(`issuer-Cert ${JSON.stringify(issuerCert.subject)} - valid from: ${issuerCert ? issuerCert.valid_from : 'invalid'} valid till: ${issuerCert ? issuerCert.valid_to : 'invalid'}`);
    const rootCert = issuerCert.issuerCertificate;
    console.log(`root-Cert ${JSON.stringify(rootCert.subject)} - valid from: ${rootCert ? rootCert.valid_from : 'invalid'} valid till: ${rootCert ? rootCert.valid_to : 'invalid'}`);
});
```

as proposed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48549393/1377895).

Both `axios` and `https` return an error like this:

```json
{
  "message": "certificate has expired",
  "name": "Error",
  "stack": "Error: certificate has expired\n\tat TLSSocket.onConnectSecure (_tls_wrap.js:1497:34)\n\tat TLSSocket.emit (events.js:315:20)\n\tat TLSSocket._finishInit (_tls_wrap.js:932:8)\n\tat TLSWrap.onhandshakedone (_tls_wrap.js:706:12)\n\tat TLSWrap.callbackTrampoline (internal/async_hooks.js:131:14)",
  "config": {
    "transitional": {
      "silentJSONParsing": true,
      "forcedJSONParsing": true,
      "clarifyTimeoutError": false
    },
    "transformRequest": [
      "null"
    ],
    "transformResponse": [
      "null"
    ],
    "timeout": 0,
    "xsrfCookieName": "XSRF-TOKEN",
    "xsrfHeaderName": "X-XSRF-TOKEN",
    "maxContentLength": -1,
    "maxBodyLength": -1,
    "headers": {
      "Accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*",
      "user-Agent": "axios/0.26.0"
    },
    "method": "get",
    "url": "https://..."
  },
  "code": "CERT_HAS_EXPIRED",
  "status": null
}
```

with a more human-readable stacktrace:

```
Error: certificate has expired
    at TLSSocket.onConnectSecure (_tls_wrap.js:1497:34)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at TLSSocket._finishInit (_tls_wrap.js:932:8)
    at TLSWrap.onhandshakedone (_tls_wrap.js:706:12)
    at TLSWrap.callbackTrampoline (internal/async_hooks.js:131:14)
```

while for `tls` I get the following output:

```
Connected to ...
TLS.connect authorized
Cipher: {"name":"TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256","standardName":"TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256","version":"TLSv1/SSLv3"}
Protocol: "TLSv1.3"
Peer-Cert {"CN": "*...."} - valid from: Feb  1 08:18:23 2022 GMT valid till: May  2 08:18:22 2022 GMT
issuer-Cert {"C":"US","O":"Let's Encrypt","CN":"R3"} - valid from Sep  4 00:00:00 2020 GMT valid till: Sep 15 16:00:00 2025 GMT
root-Cert {"C":"US","O":"Internet Security Research Group","CN":"ISRG Root X1"} - valid from: Jan 20 19:14:03 2021 GMT valid till: Sep 30 18:14:03 2024 GMT
```

So `tls` seems to be able to connect to the API server and perform the SSL/TLS handshake, but `https` and `axios` somehow fail.

I also stumbled upon [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69403020/axios-certificate-has-expired-on-valid-certificate) here, which seems to be related, but as I am already on the latest NodeJS release (as well as any dependency used in the extension is on the most recent version) and this error only occurs on Windows (mostly 10, unsure if and how many users actually use Windows 11) machines I think the question deserves its own spot here on SO.

In order to rule out a lack of common supported ciphers between the Windows and Node.js based `tls` implementation and the nginx managed server side, I also checked the available ciphers in Node via `node -p crypto.constants.defaultCoreCipherList` which returns a list like this:

```
TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256
TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256
DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256
ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384
DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384
ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256
DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256
HIGH
!aNULL
!eNULL
!EXPORT
!DES
!RC4
!MD5
!PSK
!SRP
!CAMELLIA
```

which indicates that enough ciphers would overlap between client and server.

Why do I still get a `certificate expired` error on Windows machines with axios/https
when Linux and MacOS work just fine with these settings and `tls` is able to connect to the remote API sucessfully even on Windows machines?

Comment: (1) some servers use different cert chains depending on SNI, and `https` (and everything above it) automatically sends SNI while `tls` does not; [try adding `{serverername:hostname}`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v16.x/api/tls.html#tlsconnectoptions-callback) (2) the third cert in server's chain isn't necessarily a root, and for LetsEncrypt in particular it is usually a cert whose _subject_ is ISRG Root X1 as you show but is in fact not a root but a _bridge_ to DST Root X3, to support old Androids ...

Comment: ... (3) if you are using node _in a Linux distro package_ it probably uses the system-installed version of OpenSSL, and possibly the system-installed truststore; AIUI MacOS normally has LibreSSL installed rather than OpenSSL, although brew or ports provides OpenSSL, so I don't know which a nodejs package(r) would use, and typically doesn't supply an OpenSSL-format truststore so it would use the nodejs-upstream one from Mozilla (3) Windows normally doesn't have OpenSSL, so a build for Windows probably has embedded OpenSSL and nodejs-upstream truststore

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 thanks for your comments. ad 1) I moved hostname and port to the options as well as the servername as suggested by you but it doesn't make any differences here. I am also less interested in `tls` but in getting Axios to work without having to disable cert-checks (i.e. by using `https.globalAgent.options.rejectUnauthorized = false`). I only used `tls` to showcase that the certs are valid and tls connections are actually possible. ad 3) I also "feared" that Node uses its own private truststore and currently providing/shipping a custom one is probably not an option desired